# Logarithmic y with zero in GnuPlot

Tags: gnuplot

My goal is to display 0 values on a logarithmic scale a little bit under 1.

I managed to plot my own simple histogram (`with boxes`) with logarithmic Y scale. My Y values are non-negative integers up to 25000. I cannot differentiate the 0 and 1 values as the Y scale begins at 1. Which is mathematically correct, but I want to hack a zero just under the one.

If I were to write a program that plots my graph, I would add 1 to all of my data, and remove 1 from the Y labels. Is there any tricks that would do something like that for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
gnuplot> set xrange [0:2]
gnuplot> set log y
gnuplot> set yrange [0.1:100]
gnuplot> set ytics ("0" 0.1, "1" 1, "10" 10)
gnuplot> plot cosh(x)
gnuplot>
```

Comment: @Cristoph OP: «I want to hack a zero just under the one» and I hacked a zero under the one. Not exactly her/his use case, yes, but imho the OP is smart enough to catch the under tone.

Comment: I don't get the downvote you got. Your approach is excellent! I used `set yrange [0.5:*]` and `set ytics ("0" 0.5, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000)` and the result is neat. Elegant even.

Comment: @Notinlist It's my fault, in a way... my answer was written for you and not for the occasional DV that has not the time (the willingness?) to understand.  Thank you for the appreciation, the only thing really worth the time spent on SO.

Comment: @Christoph I appreciate your time spent on editing, but in my opinion the interactive interpreter prompts, that you have removed, added to the sense of immediacy of my answer, and also testified (in a measure...) that I actually tested my proposal before submitting.  OTOH I don't want to contest, not another time! your understanding of my answer and so I'll let it go. Thank you for your time, ciao from

Comment: @gboffi Actually I did the edit so that I could remove the downvote, that's it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best option would be to plot your histogram using a modified function:

```
plot 'data' using 1:($2 < 1 ? $2 : log10($2)+1) with boxes
```

The above command plots the log10()+1 of your data if it is above or equal to 1, otherwise it plots simply your data. Then, you can modify your y axis so that it's linear between 0 and 1 and logarithmic between 1 and the highest value:

```
ymax = 10000
set yrange [0:log10(ymax)]
unset ytics
set ytics 1 add ("0" 0, "1" 1)
set for [i=2:log10(ymax)] ytics add (sprintf("%g",10**(i-1)) i) # Add major tics
set for [i=1:log10(ymax)] for [j=2:9] ytics add ("" log10(10**i*j) 1) # Add minor tics
set for [j=1:9] ytics add ("" j/10. 1) # Add minor tics between 0 and 1
plot 'data' using 1:($2 < 1 ? $2 : log10($2)+1) with boxes
```

The 1 after the tic position is to adjust the minor tics' length (thanks to @Christoph). Anyway, this looks like the following figure for a test case x^2, where you can see how the y axis is linear up to 1 and logarithmic beyond:

[image]

Comment: To set minor tics, use `1` for the level: `set for [i=1:log10(ymax)] for [j=2:9] ytics add ("" log10(10**i*j) 1)`.

Comment: Very good for values between 0 and 1. Out of scope, but I can't help to ask. Will the numbers at the mouse will be correct for SVG output? (My GNUPlot is too old to test that feature. It's that out of scope. :-))

Comment: @Christoph Thanks, I fixed it. You're spot on as usual.

Comment: @Notinlist The values that gnuplot is processing beyond y = 1 are actually the log10() of your data + 1. I'm not familiar with SVG output, but perhaps you can modify the mouse output to show you the correct value using the transformation mouse = 10^(y - 1) or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you. this is not just a "hack", but a real way to have a linear-log y axis on gnuplot:

```
reset
set terminal wxt 0 enhanced font 'Sans,13'  

#%%%  SIZE SETTINGS (whole figure)
tm = 0.90; bm = 0.2   
lm = 0.12; rm = 0.885
size = 0.8

#%%%  RANGE SETTINGS
y1 = 0.; y2 = 1.;       #(lin interval)
y3 = 1.; y4 = 1000.;   #(log interval)

x1 = -8.0; x2 = 8.0
set xrange [x1:x2]; 

#%%%  SIZE SETTINGS (single plots)
I_1 = abs(y2-y1)
I_2 = abs(log10(y4)-log10(y3))
denom = I_1 + I_2

T_m_1 = lm + size * (I_1/denom)
T_m_2 = lm + size * ((I_1+I_2))/denom)


f(x) = (15.*sin(x)/x)**2


#%%%  BEGIN MULTIPLOT
set multiplot

# Left and Right margins
set lmargin at screen lm
set rmargin at screen rm

# X-axis settings:  
set xlabel "X [ux]"; set format x "%2.1f";
set xtics 2 nomirror; set mxtics 4
do for [i=(x1+1):(x2-1):2]  { 
  set xtics add ("" i)      }

set samples 10000;

# Y-axis label
set label 'Y [uy]'  \
at screen 0.03,bm + 0.5*size \
offset 0,-strlen("X [ux]")/4.0 \
rotate by 90

#%% First plot, first interval
set border 1+2+8
set bmargin at screen bm
set tmargin at screen T_m_1

set yrange [y1:y2]

set format y "%1.0f"; 
set ytics 1; set mytics 5;


plot f(x) lw 2 \
lc rgb "navy" notitle
#%% End first plot

unset xlabel; unset xtics     

#%% Second (and last) plot
set border 2+4+8
set bmargin at screen T_m_1
set tmargin at screen T_m_2

# showing mirror xtics via a x2 axis
set link x via x inverse x
set format x2 ""; 
set x2tics nomirror; set mx2tics 4;
do for [i=(x1+1):(x2-1):2]  { 
 set x2tics add ("" i)      }

set logscale y;
set ytics autofreq; set mytics autofreq; 
set format y "10^{%L}";  
set ytics add ("" 1.0);

set yrange [y3:y4]

plot f(x) lw 2 \
lc rgb "navy" notitle
#%% End second plot

unset multiplot
#%%%  END MULTIPLOT
```

Result:
[image](https://scontent-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13891851_284651675227345_2122330916030139981_n.png?oh=2bf95a5d23707136d122cae131e7fe8f&oe=5858B816)

Practical guide to the code:

- start by modifying the "RANGE SETTINGS" to adapt them to your plot
- then choose the "X-axis settings" and "Y-axis label" you prefer
- comment the two lines specifying the ytics and yformat in the "first plot" part (aka let Gnuplot set those for you, for now)
- modify "first" plot command to plot (between y1 and y2) your function/datafile
- adapt the part under "showing mirror xtics via a x2 axis" to your X axis setting (if you want specular tics)
- modify "second" plot command to plot (between y3 and y4) your function/datafile
- see the result and fix minor details, like labels, formats, tics, mtics, and so on.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers this question? Code dumps don't really teach :)

Comment: It's a re-adapted version of the "broken-axis" example found here: 
[link](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.it/2010/06/broken-axis-once-more.html).
Basically you plot your function (or your datafile) in two steps, firstly the linear interval, then the log one.

Comment: @TimMalone I added a guide to the code, if you are interested.