# gnuplot : using a logarithmic axis for a histogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have a data file that I am creating a histogram from.

The data file is :

```
-0.1  0  0  JANE
1  1  1  BILL
2  2  1  BILL
1  3  1  BILL
6  4  0  JANE
35 5  0  JANE
9  6  1  BILL
4  7  1  BILL
24 8  1  BILL
28 9  1  BILL
9  10  0  JANE
16 11  1  BILL
4  12  0  JANE
45 13  1  BILL
```

My gnuplot script is :

```
file='test.txt'
binwidth=10
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)
set boxwidth 1

plot file using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes, \
file using (1+(bin($2,binwidth))):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes
```

I would like to plot this data on a logscale in y. However there are some 0 values (because some of the bins are empty) that cannot be handled by `set logscale y`.  I get the error `Warning: empty y range [1:1], adjusting to [0.99:1.01]`.

According to gnuplot's help, "The frequency option makes the data monotonic in x; points with the same x-value are replaced by a single point having the summed y-values."

How can I take the log10() of the summed y-values computed by `smooth freq with boxes`?

Comment: Next time please add also a sample data file so that we can test your code without having to generate the data ourselves.

Comment: Thanks. Data file added.

Comment: Updated the answer with your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two things that you could do. One is to use a linear axis between 0 and 1 and then use the logarithmic one as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884670/logarithmic-y-with-zero-in-gnuplot/26887019#26887019). The other one is to plot to a `table` first and then set the log scale ignoring the points with zero value.

With a normal linear axis and your code (plus `set yrange [0:11]`) your data looks:

[image]

Now lets plot to a table, then set the log scale, then plot ignoring the zero values:

```
file='test.txt'
binwidth=10
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)

set table "data"

plot file using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq, \
file using (1+(bin($2,binwidth))):(1.0) smooth freq

unset table

set boxwidth 1
set logscale y
set yrange [0.1:11]

plot "data" index 0 using ($1):($2 == 0 ? 1/0 : $2) with boxes lc 1, \
"data" index 1 using ($1):($2 == 0 ? 1/0 : $2) with boxes lc 2
```

[image]

`set table` sometimes generates some undesirable points in the plot, which you can see at x = 0. To get rid of them you can use `"< grep -v u data"` instead of `"data"`.

Comment: Type "help table" for the meaning of the letter. I think you need to set the ranges before plotting to table to get rid of them, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Why does it generate undesirable (i.e. 'u' type) data points?

Comment: It appears that the plot being out of range is the reason for the 'o' type.  Perhaps I should make it a separate question about the undefined type.

Comment: These questions are asked more clearly [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523266/gnuplot-data-table-type-value-u-and-strange-bars-in-histogram-boxes).